# How to do arithmetic with a formula that contains big O notation

Tags: functions, asymptotics, arithmetic

For example, I want to use the formula

$ \operatorname{foo}(n)= 1/5 \pi +\log(n) + \pi n + 1/2 + O(n^{-m}) $

How can I evaluate for $n=4$ when I know that $m>0$

Comment: You can't. O notation is meant for describing behaviour in the limit, not as something to evaluate.